# Изменение градиента при прокрутке страницы

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, градиент

Есть ли библиотека ReactJS или что либо другое, чтобы плавно изменить градиет на заднем фоне, при прокрутке страницы ? p.s - блок fixed